# Adding an item to a ListBox using Javascript works on Windows 7 but doesn't work on W2008

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, windows-7

We have two aspx pages. I'll call them Page1 and Page2. Page1 has a ListBox and a Button. The Button opens Page2. Page2 has a ListBox and a Button. The Page2 Button has an OnClientClick method that is written in Javascript. It uses window.opener to return to Page1 and passes to a Javascript function on Page1 the values of the items checked in the Page2 ListBox. Using alerts we've determined that Page2 passes the values correctly back to Page1 and the Page1 function fires. And the Page1 function works fine if we publish the website to a Windows 7 machine. However, on a Windows 2008 Standard server, when we get to the line where the values are to be added to Page1's ListBox as new ListBox items (the whole point of the exercise), the Javascript does not work. It doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't add the items to the ListBox, and any alerts inserted into the script after that point don't fire. Here's the code:

```
function ProcessFromPopup(dvalue, text) {
  var htmlSelect = document.getElementById('<%=lstSelEmployees.ClientID%>');
  var selectBoxOption = this.document.createElement("option");
  selectBoxOption.value = dvalue;
  selectBoxOption.text = text;
  htmlSelect.add(selectBoxOption, null);
  return true;
}
```

As I said, the line with "htmlSelect.add" doesn't do anything, and any alerts inserted after that line don't fire. An alert inserted directly above that line does fire. So what are we doing wrong? We're using .Net 4.0 framework. Also, this is a behavior seen in IE9 and 10, but *not* in Chrome or Safari. In Chrome and Safari, the code works fine.

Comment: Step through your javascript using your browser's developer tools.

Comment: From MDN: "While DOM manipulation methods, such as `add()` and `remove()` can be used to modify the collection as child node objects of the select object, this is not guaranteed to be supported by all browser platforms." - I'm not sure what browsers they're referring to and what browser you're testing on, but does it not work on all browsers?

Comment: I would also double check the generated html to make sure that `<%=lstSelEmployees.ClientID%>` is indeed outputting a valid id, and that there is a `<select>` element with that id on the page.

Comment: Try removing `this.` from `this.document.createElement("option");`

Comment: @Lee Taylor - Visual Studio isn't installed on the server, so I can't step through the Javascript there.

Comment: @Jonah - the ListBox outputs a valid client id and there is a select element with that id on the page.

Comment: @Palash Mondal - removing "this" has no effect.

Comment: @Ian - I suspect this is the crux of the problem, but why would IE work if the website's on a Windows 7 machine but not on a W2008 box? Either way we're using Windows 7 to view the website. Would it make a difference if the website is on the user's local machine or not? Most importantly, is there a workaround?

Comment: @Melanie. No, use your **browser's** built-in debugging tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My co-worker just figured this out. IE9 on up needs a slightly different syntax. Instead of creating the selectBoxOption, you just do this:

```
htmlSelect.add(new Option(text, dvalue));
```

"new" is the key here. Thanks to everyone for their help, and sorry to waste your time. We'd been banging our heads against this for three days and my co-worker finally found the answer.